# Sequential number i n Symfony php

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to make a sequential number for facture reference, but I can't know who to proceed,
I already do something like this with Twig php

```
{% set debut = "Ref" %}
    {% set date = 'now' | date("dmY") %}
    {% set separator = "-" %}
     {% for i in range(0000, 9999) %}
        {{ debut ~ i ~ separator ~ date}},
     {% endfor %}
```

This code give me the sequential number between 1-9999 but I want to have just reference Ref0001-28092017 if is not already exist in my facture.

Please, help me to solve my probleme, how do I proceess for this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding zeroes using `format` filter:

```
{% set debut = "Ref" %}
{% set date = 'now' | date("dmY") %}
{% set separator = "-" %}
{% for i in range(0000, 9999) %}
    {% set i_pad = "%04d" | format(i) %}
    {{ debut ~ i_pad ~ separator ~ date}},
{% endfor %}
```

That seems to work: https://twigfiddle.com/vyvh2e.

Comment: ok thanks, it's woork perfectly? 
and how can I get one Reference by one, because here give me all reference?

Comment: Such logic does not belong to the template level. This should be done in the code and put into the model.